# staging database always picked from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rake task in my app written in this way under the /lib/tasks folder

```
task :import_feed => :environment do
  url = "url"
  decode json here
  post=Post.new
  post.attributes
  post.save
end
```

Everytime i run this task i get and error that the staging database is not configured. Doesn't matter if i do RAILS_ENV=production or RAILS_ENV=development. What can be the cause of that?

Comment: is that a typo? `environment` instead of `:environment`

Comment: i managed to fix it already  it was a misconfig of rails. Thanks